# QUiLoader ignores resource file

Tags: c++, qt

If you need to load .ui file dynamically, you can use QUiLoader mechanism. But if you are using external resources in your .ui file (if there is something like `<resources><include location=".../filename.qrc"/></resources>` in .ui file), Qt will not load it.

I.e. if you open your .ui file in Qt Designer, you will see all bitmaps on buttons and other resources. But if you load the same .ui file via QUiLoader, you will not see bitmaps on buttons.

Is it a problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you've used your .qrc file when creating a .ui file already, the file will always need to be added to the project itself.

There are a number of Qt tools that get used in the precompilation stage. The following are the most commonly used ones but there are others:

1. The Meta Object Compiler (moc) creates `moc_xxx.cpp` files from
   header files if they contain the Q_OBJECT macro (or `xxx.moc` if
   scanning a cpp file).
2. The Resource Compiler (rc) creates `qrc_xxx.cpp` files from .qrc
   files.
3. The User Interface Compiler (uic) creates `ui_xxx.h` files from
   .ui files.

Any tool that creates a source file (.cpp) will then have to have to have this code compiled and linked into the application if it's going to be useful.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! Now it seems obvoius, but when I faced with this problem it was not so clear. So I decided to add this question and answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem, but specific moment: QUiLoader never load data from .qrc files described in .ui files. So right solution is to include .qrc file in your current project too. It looks strange (because you've already included link to .qrc file into your .ui file), but it is specific moment in using of QUiLoader.